# C# WPF Media Video Player doesn't start

Tags: c#, wpf, video, media-player

I try to make a Media Player on WPF.

I made this yet  :

```
     public partial class MyMediaPlayer : Window
    {
        public MyMediaPlayer()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            //

            OpenFileDialog dlg = new OpenFileDialog();
            dlg.InitialDirectory = "c:\\"; // init

            dlg.Filter = "All Files (*.*)|*.*"; // filter
            dlg.RestoreDirectory = true;
            // dialog window
          if (dlg.ShowDialog() == true) // checked ? 
            {
                string selectedFileName = dlg.FileName; // path of the media
                MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer();
                player.Open(new Uri(selectedFileName, UriKind.Relative));
                VideoDrawing aVideoDrawing = new VideoDrawing();
                aVideoDrawing.Rect = new Rect(0, 0, 100, 100);
                aVideoDrawing.Player = player; // play
                // never play
                player.Play();
            }
        }
    }
```

And the XAML file :

```
    <Window ... >
    <Grid>
        <MediaElement Margin="10,10,10,0 " Source="D:\test.avi"
                              Name="McMediaElement"
                 Width="450" Height="250" LoadedBehavior="Manual" UnloadedBehavior="Stop" Stretch="Fill"
                 />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

But, the video never start, and the window stay white.

Help please :)

ps : sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 1):

MediaPlayer Class ([msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.media.mediaplayer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)):

> MediaPlayer is different from a MediaElement in that it is not a
>   control that can be added directly to the user interface (UI) of an
>   application. To display media loaded using MediaPlayer, a VideoDrawing
>   or DrawingContext must be used.

So if you want to use MediaPlayer you should use `DrawingBrush` class:

```
...
string selectedFileName = dlg.FileName; 
MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer();
player.Open(new Uri(selectedFileName, UriKind.Relative));
VideoDrawing aVideoDrawing = new VideoDrawing();
aVideoDrawing.Rect = new Rect(0, 0, 100, 100);
aVideoDrawing.Player = player;                 
player.Play();
DrawingBrush DBrush = new DrawingBrush(aVideoDrawing);
this.Background = DBrush;
...
```

In this solution you don't have to add `MediaElement` in XAML.

To play media in XAML only, use a `MediaElement` ([msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.mediaelement%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)).

XAML:

```
<MediaElement  Name="McMediaElement" Source="D:\test.avi"
         LoadedBehavior="Play" UnloadedBehavior="Stop" Stretch="Fill"
         Margin="10,10,10,0" Width="450" Height="250"
            />
```

Code-behind:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    OpenFileDialog dlg = new OpenFileDialog();
    dlg.InitialDirectory = "c:\\"; 

    dlg.Filter = "All Files (*.*)|*.*"; // filter
    dlg.RestoreDirectory = true;    
    if (dlg.ShowDialog() == true) 
    {
        string selectedFileName = dlg.FileName;     
        McMediaElement.Source = new Uri(selectedFileName, UriKind.Absolute);        
    }
}
```

Comment: @user1785316 could you prepare example solution and upload to e.g. skydrive?